# How to transfer vertex paint from one mesh to another - without copying other data

Tags: vertex-colors

I need to transfer vertex volors from one mesh to another. They are the same but first one has normals that i want to keep, second contains vertex color i want to transfer but doesn't have normal info. I cant transfer object data with ctrl+L because it also transfers normals that i want to keep.
Is there a way to transfer only vertex color?

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is a "Data Transfer"

Let's say we have 2 cubes
[image]

One of them has colored vertex, the other does not. to transfer the colored vertex data, make sure both objects are in the same position, basically overlapping each other.
select object without colors first, then shift select object with colors second.
Press F3 and Search for "transfer mesh data" and click on it. then select
vertex color

[image]

you can also achieve this by using the "Data Transfer" modifier, its also good for visualizing the output before applying it, or if you want to make it dynamic

Comment: Thank you for reply! i will be trying it soon

Comment: It doesnt seem to work for my mesh :( is there some way i can attach my blend file ?

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/?ref=be-community-add-2 this site allows you to upload .blend  files and paste the link in your post to be available for download :D